clang-format and TextProto / .txtpb and .textproto files
Modern clang-format supports text format protobuf. I have a simple .clang-format file:
---
BasedOnStyle: Google
---
Language: TextProto
ColumnLimit: <CHANGE_ME>

I have the following sample / wanted output:
parent {
  child {
    int: 123
    qstr: "some text"
    str: some text
  }
}

With column width 120, I get everything on one line - as expected, I guess, since it fits on one line:
parent { child { int: 123 qstr: "some text" str: some text } }
With column width 1, I get almost what I want:
parent {
  child {
    int:
        123
    qstr: "some text"
    str: some
        text
  }
}

The problem is that fields with integers and unquoted strings break and I have no clue why. Is there anyway to avoid this? I have tried a lot of settings that doesn't seem to affect TextProto.
